# Использовать внешнюю переменную в функции

Tags: javascript

```js
let author = 'John';
let admin = 'John';

if(isAdmin()){
  console.log('проверка прошла')
} else {
  console.log('проверка не прошла')
}

function isAdmin(){
  return author == admin;
}
```

Пишет что author is not defined. Можно сделать isAdmin(author), но я хотел бы покороче. Как сделать чтобы оно видело author?

Comment: `Error: admin is not defined` - `admin`, а не `author`.

Comment: Это для примера. У меня идет длинная проверка на админа.

Comment: Пример - плохой. Сделайте хороший.

Comment: У вас функция ничего не возвращает. `return author === admin;`

Comment: @Deonis Это не должно приводить к такой ошибке. По крайней мере, в приведенном коде.

Comment: Где и как это запускается?

Comment: «Можно сделать isAdmin(author)» — даже нужно) Короче - не всегда лучше: Когда функция использует внешние переменные, нужно постоянно париться и думать про области видимости. А `isAdmin(author)` при таком варианте, функция может находиться где угодно, и даже не знать, что ему подсунули в качестве параметра... сделать проверку и вернуть результат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я не там определил функцию.

```
{
  Блок в котором появляется author и используется isAdmin()
}

function isAdmin(){
  объявлена вне того блока
}
```

Когда нужно вот так:

```
{
  Блок в котором появляется author и используется isAdmin()

  function isAdmin(){
    объявлена в этом блоке
  }
}
```